# Raspberry Pi not discoverable on WLAN

Tags: networking, wifi, ipv6

My Raspberry Pi4, running a standard Raspberry OS 32, can be found with its hostname on my LAN when it is connected with a cable. However, when connected only via WLAN, I cannot ping or ssh it with its hostname. Using the literal ipv4 address, it *can* be addressed.
On my router, I have found that all devices having an ipv6 address, are discoverable from a PC. So I would like to turn on ipv6 on the WLAN interface, as it seems that the Pi is not requesting an address at the DHCP on the router.
Can someone help how to do that or has an alternative solution? Thanks!

Peter

hl@raspi10:~ $ ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether dc:a6:32:f7:2e:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether dc:a6:32:f7:2e:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.93/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
valid_lft 85868sec preferred_lft 75068sec
inet6 fe80::dc55:91b8:8db6:93fc/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

hl@raspi10:~ $ ip r

default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.93 metric 303
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.93 metric 303

Comment: You have omitted ANY details from your question. What OS? How is networking configured? How are you trying to connect? What do `ip a` && `ip r` show.

Comment: Your router may have AP isolation active. That prevents WiFi devices communicating. Disable that on the router's settings pages.

Comment: thanks that is a good suggestion. My router does not support AP isolation but I will search further along that line.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have replaced the router and now it is working again. Thanks @Dougie for pointing in the right direction.